# stored procedure String parameter returns null for some parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a new stored procedure in MySQL,

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getEmpById`(IN empId INT, 
   OUT empSal DOUBLE, out empName varchar(45))
BEGIN

 select salary,empname into  empSal,empName from employee where empno=empId;

END
```

in MySQL workbench and table structure is 
[image]

but while executing it

```
call getEmpById(1,@empSal,@empName);
select @empSal,@empName;
```

it returns the result, but it returns value only for empSal, not for empName or not for others also

my out is like

```
|@empName |@empSal |
--------------------
|null     |55500   |
```

Comment: Did you check empname available? Might be there is no value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution myself,

```
     select salary,empname into  empSal,empName from employee
```

in my stored procedure, I am mapping the column name `empname` to `empName` that's why I am getting `null` values as ouput

In stored procedure, you cant use `parameter name` same as the `column name`.

after changing parameter   `empname` to `ename` I got correct result which i want.